# cross-domain http post without preflight

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

is it possible to do a cross domain http "post" without preflight "options" if i'm not interested in parsing the response?

Comment: What are "preflight options", and are you talking about an AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain old `<form>` element to post data to another domain. Its `target` attribute may ba a name of an invisible `<iframe>` element. This would prevent reloading the page after form has been submitted. 
Both form and iframe may be in html source hidden using CSS, or created on-the-fly in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible if you post **text/plain**
From Fx 4.0 you can use any enctype.
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control